# Group by column then Sum group table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report on Business Objects which i would like to replicate on Power BI. On BO, it groups a column and gives the sum of the total in the table per group. I have provided an example to give clarity on the query. I think in the example provided, it is grouped by column Delivery Litres. I would like to produce the same output in Power BI

TIA

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you trying to write a measure for a visual or create a calculated table of some sort? What does your data table look like (e.g. the shown table with/without the highlighted rows)? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I am trying to recreate the table above. The data source is a sql query and the user has formatted the table as above in Business Objects to show the Sum values. Otherwise it is a flat table I have.

Comment: So the input is that flat table without the highlighted row. It's still not clear what your output is. Do you intend to display it as a matrix visual on a report?